# Is there an equivalent for the "goto" loop in C# in lua? (Must be compatible with Love2D)

Tags: lua, love2d

I'm currently coding a game for a school project, a sort of Space Invader type of game. I'm currently trying to make a screen where it says "Press R to restart" so that when the player presses R the games goes back to the start. Like in C# exemple : Start: (all your code) goto Start. So my question is there an equivalent of this? I cannot find something about that on the internet.

I've already tried the return loop but it crashes the game before it even starts. I saw that Lua actually has a goto loop in the 5.2 version. But Love2D only supports Lua 5.1 so now I've tried repeat ... until (condition) but it still doesn't work

### Beginning of the code :

```
repeat

score = 0
enemykills = 0
local start = love.timer.step( )
```

### End of the code :

```
    love.graphics.setColor(255, 255, 255)
    for _,b in pairs(player.bullets) do
      love.graphics.rectangle("fill", b.x, b.y, 2, 2)
    end
end
until not love.keyboard.isDown("r")
```

I want the game to restart when I press R but it either crashes or does nothing.

Comment: Your condition is wrong, it should be `until love.keyboard.isDown("r")`. So if you press the "R"-button it will stop the repeat. But I don't think this will solve your inital problem.

Comment: My try would be to put the action code into a function `run()` or sth. else, which calls itself if the condition is fulfilled.

Comment: "*Like in C# exemple : Start: (all your code) goto Start*" You shouldn't do that in C# either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Love2D will call your `love.update` and `love.draw` functions repeatedly. You don't need to have such a loop. What you need to do is remember that your game is in the "wait for user to press 'r' to restart" state. So your code would look something like this:

```
local current_state = "normal"

function love.update(dt)
    if(current_state == "wait") then
        if(love.keyboard.isDown("r")) then
            current_state == "normal"
        end
    else
        --[[Do normal processing]]
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!